# htaccess pretty URL shows no css or images in PHP MVC

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, url-routing

First time playing around with htaccess to create a pretty-url project together with a simple PHP project structure. I got my pretty url's about OK-ish, the only problem I have, for now, is that my CSS/media/... isn't loaded on the page.

Here's the htaccess code I use:

```
RewriteEngine on

# localhost
RewriteBase /project/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2

# fix trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Everything needs to be routed to the index.php file and my general pattern would look like this:

```
.com/desktops
.com/laptops
.com/desktop/Intel-Core-i5-Gaming
.com/laptop/Intel-Core-i5-Gaming
```

I hope someone of you can teach me some wisdom on this! :)

Comment: you need to tell apache not to route css, fonts and others by excluding them,you can do something like `RewriteRule !\.(js|gif|jpg|png|css|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|svg)$ `

Comment: @adelowo He rewrites to only those that are non-existant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

OR there are 3 different ways to solve this problem:

Use absolute paths for images, css and js files i.e. start your path with / or http://

Another one is to use base href tag in HTML head section like this:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/">
```

3rd option is via mod_rewrite

Put these lines above your other RewriteLine in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/([^.]+\.(?:js|css|jpe?g|png|gif))$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: This works with 1 parameter, when the second parameter is added it's back to no css/media/...

Comment: Using the `<base href="http://www.example.com/">` fixed my problem.

I'm not sure where I'm supposed to put the last lines you wrote in htaccess. If I were to fix this problem in htaccess only, could you tell me where to put those?

Comment: @Nerdben Check my answer. I gave the same thing first. I know that issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have added your CSS like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/media/..." />
```

It will not work, because of your routing, it goes to different places, like getting into subdomain (which actually doesn't exist). So consider using relative path to the domain:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/CSS/media/..." />
<!---------------------------^ add a slash here.
```